# how to write a recipe for copy a file from one VM to another VM

Tags: chef-infra

How to write the chef script for copy a file from one VM to another VM.. And Is it possible to copy a file from one node to another node using recipes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef does on its own, you would have to automate it using whatever tools you would use without Chef. For example, a recipe on one server to install and configure and rsync service and another recipe to download a file from it.